# What to do when I have energy loss due to distance

Tags: voltage, motor, wire, conductors

I have to connect a total of 15 12 V, 2 A motors in parallel.

They are all going to be connected to a battery and I’m trying to bring a line to connect all 15 of them. The distance between them is 25 meters. What can I do to reduce the energy loss due to the distance?

Comment: How much power are you losing? What gauge wire are you using? What is your power source?

Comment: I’m using 12 gauge wire .. the distance between each motor is 25 meters .. and I’m using a solar battery 12V 65AH

Comment: what is the layout of the motors? put the battery closest to the middle of the group

Comment: Are the motors always in a straight line or can you affect the geometry?

Answer (score 3):

Everyone seems to be suggesting the thicker wire route here.. but you do have a different option.

Your other alternative is to either use a boost convertor to convert your 12V into a high DC voltage or use an invertor to make high voltage AC and transmit that down cheaper cabling instead. Then add DC-DC or AC-DC power regulators at each motor.

That may seem extreme, but you need to do a cost comparison of which is cheaper. Big beefy hard to manage cables, or cheap wiring and low cost convertors.

The other benefit of this route is you separate the power transfer efficiency issue from the target voltage-drop issue. That is, the system ought to be 100% functional despite the transmission costs.

Comment: While everyone is trying to solve this like Edison, you add some Tesla to it. The best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue here is wire size, since you did not mention any issues with battery life.

Based on your comment your pulling 30 amps of current through a 12 awg wire. Normally 20 amps is the limit for 12 gauge, but for some industries it has to do with how hot the wire gets.

Go up to 8 awg wire, coarse or fine stranded, and that should fix the problem. To be safe the (-) wire is normally black while the (+) wire is red. You could go up to 6 awg wire but the cost starts to go up quickly.

Use 6 awg (gauge) only if the voltage drop is serious, as in you have a long distance from the battery to the furthest motor.

You could run 6 awg dedicated wire to each motor instead of motor-to-motor, but the wire cost goes up because you have the distance issue.

Answer (score 1):

An online voltage drop calculator says the voltage drop for 30 amps dc current in a 25 meter run of copper sire is 7.82 V for No. 12 wire, 3.09 V for No. 8 and 1.22 V for No. 4. If the wiring needs to run 25 feet between motors, you need to add the voltage drops between each segment between from a given motor to the source.

If you run a pair of wires from each motor directly to the source and you have 375 meters to the furthest motor, you would need no. 4 wire for 10% voltage drop. If the first motor is only 25 meters away, no. 14 wire could be used for that one.

Comment: I think the OP is saying she has 15 runs of 25 meters each as a hop from motor to motor. That is a long run for 12 awg wire.

Comment: Revised answer to correct original voltage drop calculation and expand to cover motor-to-motor calculation

Comment: What do you mean add the voltage drops ..? Yes I was trying to cover 374 meters in a single line .. but  What about if I don’t connect them a straight line ? Instead I connect them like a star ? The battery in the middle and motors around it ? Like a star ? *

Comment: +1. Thanks for running the numbers. It means that the OP might have to use 4 awg wire for just a tolerable loss at the furthest motor. That is a lot of money for wire.

Comment: @VivianaTejada. That is assuming each wire run is of equal length. If you can do that it will save you much money. You could just use 8 awg then.

Comment: If the motors are arranged so a star connection would work, that is best. If they are in a line and the battery must be at one end, only the line to the first motor carries full current each successive segment carries less, thus you add 15 different 25 m drops to get to the voltage at the farthest motor and can use successively smaller wire as you go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loosing energy due to the length of the wire then buy a thicker wire.  Alternatively you could also use multiple smaller cables in parallel to create the equivalent of a thicker wire.

15 motors that are 2A each is 30A total.

The wire gauge table...

https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

...says you need at least at 6 AWG or larger wire for 30A.  Or if you are wiring each motor separately then 18 AWG wire for 2A each motor.

A 6 AWG wire has a resistance of 1.295 mOhms per meter.  I am not sure exactly how the motors are physically arranged but assuming the 30A went through all 25m then the total voltage drop would be...

1.295 mOhm/m * 25 m * 30A = 0.972V drop going to the loads and another 0.972V coming back.

The total voltage seen by the motor would then be 12V - 0.972V * 2 = 10.05V.

If you need to reduce the losses further then use a 0 AWG or 1 AWG cable, or more smaller cables.